# v-bind not working in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    <div class="background-wrapper" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + item.image + ')' }"></div>
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
</div>
```

The background-image style is set to undefined and i don't know why.
The `item.title` works. When i change `item.title` to `item.image` it prints out the correct url.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a simple snippet with your problem?

Comment: A simple snippet works for me.

Comment: Do you mean this: `background-image: url("undefined");` by undefined background-image style? If so, then the image attribute is undefined. Typo maybe?

Comment: @JanHusák "When i change `item.title` to `item.image` it prints out the correct url."

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code,  make sure that your container actually has a height and a width, e.g.:

```
.background-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

And that the image actually exists, Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xvph0ehs/

Comment: That snippet works for me.
But i wasn't work with the data i had. But now it works because i have change it to

v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(\'' + item.image + '\')' }

Comment: You can also use the shortcut way of `v-bind:style` to `:style="{}"`, and this applies to most of the html attributes i.e `:class="{}"` instead of `v-bind:class`